# CreateMap open generics ForMember child children

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a domain model of

```
Order -> List <OrderItem> OrderItems
    OrderItem contains many members and also
       Item
       Item contains many members, and also
           List<Detail> Details
```

The simplified source is the DTO and looks like

```
Order -> List <OrderItem> OrderItems
    OrderItem contains
       many item members and also
       List<Detail> Details
```

So when I create the map from DTO to Domain for the OrderItem and Item of the Domain:

```
    CreateMap(typeof(OrderItemDto), typeof(OrderItemDomain))
            .ForMember(nameof(OrderItemDomain.Item), opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src))
```

But...

how do I map the DTO OrderItem Details to the OrderItemDomain.Item.Details?

Basically, I need something comparible to below (the format of which is invalid):

```
//     .ForMember(dest=> dest.Item.Details,
//         o=> o.MapFrom(src => src.Details));
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.